# How to use multiple count and group by condition in single SQL query

Tags: sql, count, group-by, union-all

Below is my SQL Table.

```
    Id   FileName       Code1    Code2
    1   002-03_001.tif  Y179     Y179
    2   002-03_002.tif  Y178     Y178
    3   002-03_003.tif  Y177     Y177
    4   002-03_004.tif  Y178     Y179
    5   002-03_005.tif  Y177     Y179
    6   002-03_006.tif  Y179     Y178
    7   002-03_007.tif  Y178     Y178
    8   002-03_008.tif  Y178     Y177
    9   002-03_009.tif  Y177     Y179
    10  002-03_010.tif  Y178     Y177
```

From above table I want make count of Code1 and code2 like,

```
  Code1 Count1 Code2 Count2
  Y177   3      Y177    3
  Y178   2      Y178    3
  Y179   5      Y179    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to do something like this
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a01de/1)

**Sample Data**

```
create table table1
(
Id int,FileName VARCHAR(100),Code1 VARCHAR(10),Code2 VARCHAR(10)
)

insert into table1 values(    1,   '002-03_001.tif',  'Y179',     'Y179'),
    (2   ,'002-03_002.tif',  'Y178',     'Y178')
    ,(3   ,'002-03_003.tif',  'Y177',     'Y177')
    ,(4   ,'002-03_004.tif',  'Y178',     'Y179')
    ,(5   ,'002-03_005.tif',  'Y177',     'Y179')
    ,(6   ,'002-03_006.tif',  'Y179',     'Y178')
    ,(7   ,'002-03_007.tif',  'Y178',     'Y178')
    ,(8   ,'002-03_008.tif',  'Y178',     'Y177')
    ,(9   ,'002-03_009.tif',  'Y177',     'Y179')
    ,(10  ,'002-03_010.tif',  'Y178',     'Y177')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Code1,COUNT(*) Count1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Code1
)   Code1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Code2,COUNT(*) Count2
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Code2
) Code2
ON Code1.Code1 = Code2.Code2
```